# Chat textarea has a problematic scenario with the current ability to resize it larger vertically

Tags: feature-request, design, chat

The chat textarea (`#input`) can currently be resized vertically (and horizontally). To my knowledge, on most browsers, the resize handle is on the bottom left corner of the textarea. Resizing it larger vertically by anything more than the small amount of margin between the default bottom position of the textarea and the bottom of the screen and then releasing the resize handle (mouseup event) causes the resize handle to no longer be accessible via the pointer since it is now outside the viewport. As far as I can tell, this can only then be "fixed" by either reloading the page or using the browser's devtools and editing the `height` property value.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Disable vertical resizing for the textarea by setting [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) to either `horizontal` or `inline`.
2. Set an appropriate [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)/[`max-block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-block-size) property value.

I would recommend option #1. I don't see a benefit to being able to resize the textarea vertically, since the bottom bar (`#input-area`) seems to have a fixed height. While at it, consider preventing a similar problem with horizontal resizing by setting a reasonable `max-width`/`max-inline-size` (something roughly like `100vw`/`100vi` minus the widths of the elements and margins in the bottom bar that are not the textarea)

*Not* related: [Small nitpicks with the default size and resizing of the chat box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238641/997587) (only about width of chat textarea)